# Measure the time it takes to download page/images/... using JSoup

Tags: java, time, jsoup, pageload, measure

I'm making a basic 'webmonitoring tool' with java, and i'm using the library [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). Everything works fine, but the problem is that I can't figure out when I have actually (down)loaded something. Take this for example;

```
Long start = System.nanoTime();
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://hln.be").get();
Long end = System.nanoTime();
long elapsedTime = end - start;
double seconds = (double) elapsedTime / 1000000000.0;
```

Would this be an accurate way of knowing how long it took to completely (down)load the page?
The definition of the get()-method is;
***Execute the request as a GET, and parse the result.***

So I guess this would be what I'm looking for, or is there a better way?

Same question but for images only; how do know I have downloaded all the images without actually saving them on my pc?
I'm currently doing something like this; I have a list of all the image url's, and then in a for loop I go

```
url = new URL(element.absUrl("src"));
in = url.openStream();
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

After I opened the stream and read it with the BufferedReader, does it mean I 'downloaded' them? If so I can just measure the time it takes to excecute those 3 lines to know how long it takes to download an image?

I hope I'm making myself clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the [`execute()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#execute%28%29) method, which just fetches the page and does not parse the response.

E.g.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://hln.be").execute();
```